# Unable to delete docker image via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to delete image from previous build. I'm able to get its image id, however the job dies every time it hits `docker rmi` command.

```
stage('Clean old Image') {
            steps {
                script { 
                    def imageName = "${registry}" + "/" + "${branchName}"
                    env.imageName = "${imageName}"
                    def oldImageID = sh( 
                                            script: 'docker images -qf reference=\${imageName}:\${imageTag}',
                                            returnStdout: true
                                        )

                    echo "Image Name: " + "${imageName}"
                    echo "Old Image: ${oldImageID}"

                    if ( "${oldImageID}" != '' ) {
                        echo "Deleting image id: ${oldImageID}..."
                        sh 'docker rmi -f $oldImageID'
                    } else {
                        echo "No image to delete..."
                        } 
                    }  
                }
            }
```

stage log console shows these error messages

> ```
> Shell Script -- docker rmi -f $oldImageID (self time 282ms)
> + docker rmi -f
> "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
> See 'docker rmi --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
>
> Remove one or more images
> ```

but actually, the image id is already persists as it shows in stage log

> ```
> Print Message -- Old Image: 267848fadb74 (self time 11ms)
> Old Image: 267848fadb74
> ```

Comment: Does the solution I provided works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in `"` instead of `'` with `${oldImageID}`

```
 sh "docker rmi -f ${oldImageID}"
```